# Using Inno Setup to register multiple file associations to the same executable

Tags: inno-setup, file-association

I confess that I have not tried this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; SubKey: ".mwb"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "MeetingWorkBook"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; SubKey: "MeetingWorkBook"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "Meeting Workbook"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; SubKey: "MeetingWorkBook\Shell\Open\Command"; ValueType: string; ValueData: """xyz"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "MeetingWorkBook\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "abc,0"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue

Root: HKCR; SubKey: ".srr"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "SoundRotaReport"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; SubKey: "SoundRotaReport"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "Sound Rota Report"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; SubKey: "SoundRotaReport\Shell\Open\Command"; ValueType: string; ValueData: """xyz"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "SoundRotaReport\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueData: "abc,1"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

The code was created out of the box using Inno Script Studio.

What I would like confirmed in if it is acceptable to associate two different data files with the same executable? I ask this because my software has two internal editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it's perfectly normal.

Any image viewer (`.gif`, `.jpg`, ...) or a video player (`.avi`, `.mkv`, ...) or a productivity application (`.xls`, `.xlsx`, ...) or a web browser (`.html`, `.xhtml`, ...) or an IDE (`.cpp`, `.h`, ...) do the same.